# Specifying protocol in mysql connect (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, tcp

How do you specify protocol = TCP in myql_connect()?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By reading the manual:

> Whenever you specify "localhost" or "localhost:port" as server, the MySQL client library will override this and try to connect to a local socket (named pipe on Windows). If you want to use TCP/IP, use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost".
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Interesting. Out of curiosity, are there advantages (performance) in one versus the other?

Comment: @Jason Good question. I'd expect sockets to be slightly more performant, since each request doesn't need to traverse the whole TCP/IP stack. Couldn't answer this for sure though.

Comment: @deceze, How can we interface with other protocols besides named pipe and TCP/IP?

Comment: @Pacerier Like what else for example?

Comment: @deceze, E.g. DCCP and SCTP

Comment: @Pacerier As soon as MySQL implements any of those, you'll be able to use it.

Comment: What if the MySQL client is a PHP client using `mysqli_connect` inside another Docker container ?

Comment: Any clue how to make mysqli / mysqlnd / pdo_mysql use the (TCP) protocol instead of the heuristics that there will be a socket/pipe file? Using `127.0.0.1` doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding `mysql_connect()` uses TCP/IP or socket. 
Dependable on what address you give it.

This is from PHP Manual

**Note:**
*Whenever you specify "localhost" or "localhost:port" as server, the MySQL client library will override this and try to connect to a local socket (named pipe on Windows). If you want to use TCP/IP, use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost". If the MySQL client library tries to connect to the wrong local socket, you should set the correct path as in your PHP configuration and leave the server field blank.*

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php